# JavaScript - HTTP Request for Each Element in Array

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have a script that sends HTTP requests to a website to get documents, the document IDs are kept in an array. I want to send a request for each array element and return a message based on the status from the HEAD (e.g. 200 OK).

The problem I have is that when I loop through the URL array, multiple requests are sent using only the last array element, no other element is used.

Code:

```
//send http request
function sendRequest(url) {
  var newRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

  newRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(newRequest.readyState == 4) {
      if(newRequest.status == 200) {    
        console.log("loaded: " + url);
      } else {
        console.log("Failed to load: " + url);
      }
    }
  }

  newRequest.open("HEAD", url);
  newRequest.send();
}

//send request for each url in array
for(var i = 0; i < urlArray.length; i++) {
  //get document id and append to link
  var address = "https://www.adsa.co.uk/library.dr/docs.aspx?id=" + 
                urlArray[i];
  //console.log(address + "\n");
  sendRequest(address);
}
```

Output (74 is the value of the last element in the array):
This console message is produced  `urlArray.length` times:

```
Failed to load: https://www.adsa.co.uk/library.dr/docs.aspx?id=74
```

Any ideas why the sendRequest() is not sent for each array element?

Comment: This fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y8k9wmkh/ seems to work fine. Can you change it to show your issue

Comment: Thanks @ChrisCharles, I was using `Repl.it` for testing. Executing the script in jsfiddle and jsbin worked as expected. `Repl.it` seemed to be calling sendRequest on the last iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Chris in the comments for alerting me to try jsfiddle.

The above code executes as it should, it iterates over the array and sends an HTTP request for each array element. The issue was with [repl.it](https://repl.it/), a `read-eval-print-loop` coding environment. Switching to jsbin and jsfiddle produced expected results.

[Read about REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop).

Answer (score 0):

Chrome (and Firefox) complains about invalid SSL certificate and therefore doesn’t connect:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
```